# XML Serialization in VB.NET / XmlArray / XmlArrayItem / List Of T

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I am writing a small program which generates certain xml files.

I want my xml to be structured like this:

```
<Root name="test" version="testV">
   <property name="Items">
      <property name="item1" />
      <property name="item2" />
      <property name="item3" />
   </property>
</Root>
```

This is my class for the Root(Node)

```
<XmlRoot("Root")>
Public Class Root

    <XmlAttribute("name")> 
    Property Name As String = "test"

    <XmlAttribute("version")> 
    Property Version As String = "1.0"

    <XmlElement("property")> 
    Property Items As New Items

End Class
```

This is the Items class

```
Public Class Items

    <XmlAttribute("name")> 
    Property Name As String = "Items"

End Class
```

This is my serialization

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim test1 As New Root
    SerializeToXml(test1)

End Sub

Private Sub SerializeToXml(ser As Root)

    Dim ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
    ns.Add("", "")

    With New XmlSerializer(GetType(Root))
        Using writeStream As New StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/data.xml")

            .Serialize(writeStream, ser, ns)
        End Using
    End With
End Sub

End Class
```

This is my Result from data.xml

```
<Root name="test" version"testV">
  <property name="Items"/>
</Root>
```

My Question is :

Because I want " Items " to contains more than 1 element with the name " property " how do I make that work ? i googled sth. about xmlArray and XmlArrayItem with a List of T but i cant make it work.

I would appreciate any advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the lowest-level elements haven't been defined in your class structure. I would recommend expanding your definition of the Items class to include a list of the lowest-level elements and define an entirely separate class for the lowest-level elements. I tested this code and I think it works the way you were expecting:

```
<xmlroot("Root")> 
Public Class root

    <XmlAttribute("name")> 
    Property name As String

    <XmlAttribute("version")> 
    Property version As String

    <XmlElement("property")> 
    Property items As New items

End Class

Public Class items
    <XmlAttribute("name")> 
    Property name As String

    <XmlElement("property")> 
    Property item As List(Of oneitem)

End Class

Public Class oneitem

    <XmlAttribute("name")> 
    Property name As String

End Class
```